# On the five-point set $X=\lbrace a,b,c,d,e \rbrace$, construct two topologies, one that is Hausdorff and one that is not Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

On the five-point set $X=\lbrace a,b,c,d,e \rbrace$, construct two topologies, one that is Hausdorff (other than the discrete topology) and one that is not Hausdorff  (other than the trivial topology).

I manage to construct a non-Hausdorff  topology, which is $\lbrace \emptyset,X, \lbrace a \rbrace \rbrace$. But I can't find a Hausdorff  topology after I try many posibilities. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can’t be done: the only Hausdorff topology on a finite set is the discrete topology. To see this, note that a Hausdorff topology is necessarily $T_1$, so if $X$ is the finite Hausdorff space, $\{x\}$ is closed for each $x\in X$. But then $$X\setminus\{x\}=\bigcup_{y\in X\setminus\{x\}}\{y\}$$ is the union of finitely many closed sets, so it’s a closed set itself, and $\{x\}$, its complement, is an open set. Thus, the topology is discrete.

Comment: What is $T_1$? Can explain a bit on it?

Comment: @Idonknow: I space $X$ is $T_1$ if it has the following property: if $x,y\in X$, and $x\ne y$, then there are open sets $U_x$ and $U_y$ such that $x\in U_x$ and $y\notin U_x$, and $y\in U_y$ and $x\notin U_y$. This is equivalent to saying that $\{x\}$ is a closed set for every $x\in X$. Every Hausdorff space is $T_1$: in a Hausdorff space you can even choose $U_x$ and $U_y$ to be disjoint.

Comment: erm... I still not quite understand why $\lbrace x \rbrace$ is a closed set for every $x \in X$.

Comment: it would be a nice exercise to try proving $\{x\}$ is closed for each $x\in X$ given the condition that $X$ is "$\textbf{hausdorff}$".... after seeing Mr.Brian's first line "It can’t be done: the only Hausdorff topology on a finite set is the discrete topology" I strongly feel there would be no finer solution than this approach... So, i dont want to write another solution (I am not even getting any other idea after seeing his first line)...

Comment: @Idonknow: Because its complement is open. Let $x\in X$, where $X$ is $T_1$. If $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, there is an open set $U_y$ such that $y\in U_y$ and $x\notin U_y$. Let $U=\bigcup_{y\in X\setminus\{x\}}U_y$. $U$ is open, since it’s a union of open sets. If $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, then $y\in U_y\subseteq U$, so $U\supseteq X\setminus\{x\}$. And clearly $x\notin U$, so $U=X\setminus\{x\}$. But then $\{x\}=X\setminus U$ is the complement of an open set, so it’s a closed set.